# K6 could not initialize '*path*' SyntaxError: Compiler bug: Lexical declaration for an unbound name at webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, load-testing, k6

Trying to run K6 test using web-pack
Using **[k6-template-typescript](https://github.com/grafana/k6-template-typescript)**
Have also installed winston logger and axios (k6 don't like thous two dependencies for some reason)

#### Web-pack response

```
> typescript@1.0.0 start
> webpack

asset k6-load.test.js 831 KiB [emitted] (name: k6-load.test.test) 1 related asset
orphan modules 132 KiB [orphan] 53 modules
runtime modules 1.04 KiB 5 modules
cacheable modules 676 KiB
  javascript modules 532 KiB 198 modules
  json modules 144 KiB
    ./node_modules/winston/package.json 1.51 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/mime-db/db.json 143 KiB [built] [code generated]
+ 16 modules
webpack 5.76.0 compiled successfully in 800 ms
```

#### K6 response on run command

```
 ERRO[0000] could not initialize 'dist/total-turnover.test.js': could not load JS test 'file:///Users/user/Documents/work/project/k6-tests/dist/k6-load.test.js': SyntaxError: Compiler bug: Lexical declaration for an unbound name at webpack://typescript/./node_modules/winston/lib/winston/create-logger.js:36:0
```

#### Why I need them

Axios is used for external call to get data to work with (didn't tried Httpx though)
When winston is used in file with network calls for error logs (can be removed and replaced with console.log tbh)

#### Have tried

Have tried changing web-pack target from web to node and from node to web, adding dependencies to fallback (as their child dependencies)

Comment: Does `create-logger.js:36` contain valid JavaScript?

Comment: `create-logger.js` file is in node_modules
And I'm using winston for logging in all my projects

Comment: The error comes from goja, the JS runtime used by k6: https://github.com/dop251/goja/blob/master/compiler_stmt.go#L795 – so I have to ask again: what is the content of `create-logger.js` and does it contain valid JS? It could be a bug in goja too, but without a reproducer, it cannot be fixed. Which version of k6 are you running?

Comment: I have now reported this as a bug https://github.com/dop251/goja/issues/530 after some additional investigation

Comment: The bug has now been fixed and will be released with k6 v0.47.0 on october 9th 2023. Before that the master branch already has it

Comment: Big thank you and appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/dop251/goja/issues/530) in k6 0.46 (and earlier). It [will be fixed](https://github.com/grafana/k6/pull/3308) with the upcoming [0.47](https://github.com/grafana/k6/releases/tag/v0.47.0) release.